# Connecting to MongoDB Without Credentials in AWS Glue

Tags: mongodb, aws-glue

I am trying to move my data in MongoDB to Redshift using AWS Glue. To do this, I am trying to add a connection to MongoDB. My MongoDB setup does not have credentials configured. But the *Username* and *Password* fields in the *Add Connection* page are mandatory. *Test Connection* fails on giving dummy values as they will be considered during the authentication process. Would appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem and the answer below doesn't make much sense to me. Any progress @Roopak ?

Answer (score 0):

To be upfront I haven't tried this myself, but to remove the requirement for Username and Password is easy.

Basically in the Migration Setup Wizard in the **"Authentication mode"** drop-down box select **"none"**. Default value is "password, where the username and password is mandatory.

Hope that assist.